# Laravel custom CSV exporting

Tags: php, laravel, csv, laravel-excel

I would like to know is it possible for me to edit columns before exporting my CSV file or not?

For example I have products table where has `title` `description` `created_at` `updated_at` what I want is to export something like `title` `body` as you see here i removed `created_at` , `updated_at` and also renamed my `description` column to `body` is that possible?

> I am using [this package](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel) version 2.1.0 [Info Graph](https://ibb.co/jYejpn)

[image]

#### Additional Information

currently I'm using default export code from samples, including no additional query etc. try to figure how should I change my code in order to export my data as I wish.

```
public function export() {
      $products = Product::all();
        Excel::create('products', function($excel) use($products) {
               $excel->sheet('sheet 1', function($sheet) use($products){
                $sheet->fromArray($products);
               });
        })->export('xls');
```

PS: what I try to create is exactly what [this extension](https://mirasvit.com/magento-extensions/advanced-product-feeds-generator.html) does in Magento,

[image: sss]

As you can see in this extension we are able to `change default database column names`, `add/remove columns` etc. (but i only need this two options), before export the data.

## UPDATE

I managed to get my table columns names like:

`Product model`

```
public function getTableColumns() {
    return $this->getConnection()->getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing($this->getTable());
}
```

and my `controller` is like:

```
public function export(Request $request) {
      $product = new Product;
      $list = $product->getTableColumns();
      dd($list);
      //$products = Product::select($list)->get();


      // Excel::create('products', function($excel) use($products) {
        // $excel->sheet('sheet 1', function($sheet) use($products){
           // $sheet->fromArray($products);
        // });
      // })->export('xls');
}
```

`my list dd`

```
array:27 [▼
  0 => "id"
  1 => "title"
  2 => "slug"
  3 => "imageOne"
  4 => "imageTwo"
  5 => "short_description"
  6 => "description"
  7 => "price"
  8 => "meta_description"
  9 => "meta_tags"
  10 => "arrivalDays"
  11 => "height"
  12 => "weight"
  13 => "lenght"
  14 => "width"
  15 => "sku"
  16 => "stock"
  17 => "label"
  18 => "label_from"
  19 => "label_to"
  20 => "label_color"
  21 => "status_id"
  22 => "brand_id"
  23 => "category_id"
  24 => "subcategory_id"
  25 => "created_at"
  26 => "updated_at"
]
```

#### Questions

1. How to I get to edit this column names `before export my file`?
2. How do I get checkbox for each column? (explanation below)

#### Checkbox

> I need checkbox for each column to say this column be included export
>   file or not.
>
> `example` I will uncheck `created_at` column so it will not be
>   included my exported CSV file.

## UPDATE 2

Ok, I get it to work with my custom names. There is tiny issue:

My data row will repeat twice in excel file.

`Explain`

I edited `5` columns of my database and I got `10`

[image: sdd]

## Codes

This is my updated code:

```
public function export(Request $request) {
      $products = Product::all();
      Excel::create('products', function($excel) use($products, $request) {
        $excel->sheet('sheet 1', function($sheet) use($products, $request){

          $ddd = $request->except('_token');
          foreach($ddd as $fff){
            $ddd[] = $fff;
          }

            $sheet->fromArray($products, null, 'A1', false, false);
            $sheet->row(1, $ddd);
        });
      })->export('csv');
      return redirect()->back();
}
```

any idea?

Comment: I've found my solution no longer need this question.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not transform the data before creating the excel sheet? For example:

```
$products = Product::select(
    'subject as title', 
    'body as description'
)->get();
```

EDIT:

From your provided updates, it'd be something like this:

```
public function export(Request $request)
{
     $list = [];
     foreach($request->columns as $column){
         $list[] = $column->DatabaseHeadingName . ' as ' . $column->CustomHeadingName;
     }

    $products = Product::select($list)->get();

    Excel::create('products', function($excel) use($products) {
        $excel->sheet('sheet 1', function($sheet) use($products){
            $sheet->fromArray($products);
        });
    })->export('xls');
}
```

Comment: Can I? I don't know if I can or not but that's what I want to do, first edit then export. `important part is` to be able to type my custom names and not to define them in controller, just like image at the bottom of my question.

Comment: @mafortis You should be able to. Can you make sure the above code works, if it does then you'll be able to build your query into the data you need dynamically. Could you also show an example of the form the user will submit to specify field names.

Comment: Currently I don't have any form in my panel only simple export button which is working by my function `provided in question`, what i want to be happen is like this: `1-click export button`->`2-bootstrap modal will open including all my products columns (columns not their rows)`->`3-have some checkbox to select what columns be included export file`->`4-i can change or keep my column names as they are`->`5-click save button`

Comment: base on your update, what should i loop in my panel in order to get my column names for edit? `$list ` or `$products` ? `second question` what about check boxes?

Comment: Neither.. You need to print each column in the table, as shown in your last screenshot. What about check boxes?

Comment: I don't get it! so how can i have my column names for edit before export? `checkboxes` as i mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49487888/laravel-custom-csv-exporting#comment85979578_49488071 in `no.3` + ability of editing column names before export I also need checkbox for each column to say this column be included export file or not. `example` i will uncheck `created_at` column so it will not be included my exported csv file then.

Comment: For no.3, when looping around the columns you pass back have a check for whatever you call the checkbox, if it's checked add that row to $list, if it's unchecked, don't. You can get your column names for the model of the table I'd imagine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167566/discussion-between-pyy-and-mafortis).